# Acessing array elements using a character variable

Tags: sas

suppose I have an array named: dk33 and a string `t`= "dk33" is it possible somehow to use t in order to access the elements in the array dk33.

```
data _null_;
array dk33(2) _temporary_;
dk33(1)='a';
dk33(2) ='b';
t = "dk33";
put t(1); <-- what can be done here to access the array element 1 in dk33 array?
run;
```

Comment: No. Why would you want to?

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions that look like XY problems.  http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use IF/THEN logic.

```
if t = "dk33" then put dk33(1);
```

If you used permanent variables instead of temporary variables then you could use the `VVALUEX()` function to get the formatted value of variable by its name,  But you cannot use an array reference.

```
data _null_;
  array y (4) (1:4) ;
  t='y';
  length want $32;
  want=vvaluex(cats(t,1));
  put want;
run;
```